# how to position multiple div`s with a variable as selector

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to get a bigger picture when hovering over another picture on an input field with multiple pictures.

I tried the bellow code.
But the positioning of the bigger picture does not work when i use a variable to get the mouse position.
My problem is this part of the code:

var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('\"' + popid + '\"');
..........

    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y - 320) + "px";
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x - 310) + "px";

when i alert this variable"('\"' + popid + '\"')", everything looks good,
when i put in the same as alerted manualy to the last function, everything works fine.
What do i am wrong? Please can someone give me a tip or improve the code.

This is the HTML, i cant change this, it is generated.

```
<div id= "yyy" class = ..........

<input class =.......

<label for="something" class='ClassExample1'>
something
</label>

<label for="something" class='ClassExample2'>
something
</label>
```

This is addeded by me, the id of the divs are the class names of the inputs ,
i get the class name of the input fields and make a variable from that
and try to set them for positioning the bigger pictures.

```
<div id='ClassExample1' class='Class a'>
   <p><img src="some source"/></p>
</div>

<div id='ClassExample2' class='Class a'>
   <p><img src="some source"/></p>
</div>

           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
```

This is the code that i made:

```
document.getElementById( 'id yyy' ).getElementsByClassName( 'ClassExample1' )[0].onmouseover = function() {mouseOn1()};
document.getElementById( 'id yyy' ).getElementsByClassName( 'ClassExample1' )[0].onmouseout = function() {mouseOut1()};

function mouseOn1() {document.getElementById('ClassExample1').style.display = 'block';};
function mouseOut1() {document.getElementById('ClassExample1').style.display = 'none';};

document.getElementById( 'id yyy' ).getElementsByClassName( 'ClassExample2' )[0].onmouseover = function() {mouseOn2()};
document.getElementById( 'id yyy' ).getElementsByClassName( 'ClassExample2' )[0].onmouseout = function() {mouseOut2()};

function mouseOn2() {document.getElementById('ClassExample2').style.display = 'block';};
function mouseOut2() {document.getElementById('ClassExample2').style.display = 'none';};

            .
            .
            .
            .
            .

/*Position of mouse hover picture*/

var poper;

window.onmouseover=function(e) {
     poper = (e.target.className);
};

var popid = "\'" + poper + "'\";

var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById(popid);

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y - 320) + "px";
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x - 310) + "px";
};
```

Comment: Is "id yyy" is the id of the DOM.? If  the yyy is the id you could just pass that.

Answer (score 0):

The popid and tooltipspan are not reassigned on mouse move as it is not inside the mousemove function. You could move them inside the function.

```js
var poper;
var popid;
var tooltipspan;

window.onmouseover = function(e) {
  poper = (e.target.className);
  popid = "\'" + poper + "'\";
  tooltipSpan = document.getElementById(popid);
};
```

Comment: thank you for your replay, but i am not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: i tried but i can t get any result, please can you show also how this "window.onmousemove = function (e)" function should look.